# How can I fix chromium build gclient error?

Tags: google-chrome, compiler-errors, chromium, gn, gclient

I followed the Chromium [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/HEAD/docs/windows_build_instructions.md) to build it for the Windows platform, after installing the depot tools it mentioned to use the `gclient` command to install all the Windows-specific bits needed to work with the code, including msysgit and python.

Finally, after finishing the download, I received an error that you can see below.

Can anyone help me how to fix it?

> fatal error: failed to build venv: failed to build package : cipkg.Derivation{Name:"virtualenv", Platform:"", Builder:"builtin:cipdExport", Args:[]string{"infra/3pp/tools/virtualenv  version:2@16.7.12.chromium.7\n"}, Env:[]string(nil), Inputs:[]string(nil)}: failed to build derivation: failed to export packages: exec: "cipd": cannot run executable found relative to current directory

I also installed **virtualenv** with the `pip install virtualenv` command, but there was still an error

Comment: You don't need virtualenv to build Chromium. It looks like virtualenv is causing that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see in the error `cannot run executable found relative to current directory`

you need to use the full path to your depot_tools directory instead of relative path so, the bash command should be more like :

```bash
export PATH=/absolute/path/to/depot_tools:$PATH
```

instead of

```bash
export PATH=../depot_tools:$PATH
```

and after that try moving into your chromium directory and run

```bash
fetch --nohooks chromium
```

for further info refer to the [chromium docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I was updating an old modified copy of Chromium to latest.  I uninstalled virtualenv and it didn't help.

I had to change

```
exec "${base_dir}/.cipd_bin/vpython3" "$@"
```

to

```
exec "$MYPATH/.cipd_bin/3.11/bin/python3" "$@"
```

I'm not sure why it fixed it or if I'll run into other problems but so far it works.

Answer (score 0):

Running `$ ../depot_tools/fetch breakpad` didn't work for me as well, but doing what [depot_tools tutorial](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up) tells actually helped:

> $ export PATH=/path/to/depot_tools:$PATH
> $ fetch breakpad